# spring portlet MVC and request params

Tags: spring-portlet-mvc

Im setting a number of params in a URL (page.jsp?param1=value&param2=value2). When the url is requested it passes control to a Controller class, extending AbstractConrtoller , which overrides handleRenderRequestInternal to do my logic. Inside here i try to retrieve the request attributes using request.getAttribute and getParameter however neither return a value.

Any ideas how i can access the params?

Do i need to get an instance of the HttpSession and then make the lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be due to a [redirected request](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) ([forward and include](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) won't change the parameter). A [multi-part request](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html) (i.e. file upload request) would be without parameters in the request, too.

Request parameter will not end up in the Session.